# Flutter: How to set a Observer entire app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So, I'm trying to create a chat app and trying to get the user presence but after reading tons of articles on web I still don't get it how I can make it work.. So I'm trying another approach, how can I make a Observer that checks the entire app?

For example right now I have one that I use to tell Firebase Firestore when I'm chatting with someone (setting ID so Cloud Functions don't notify about new message) and I want to use it to tell Firestore when user is online/offline. Is it possible? Thank you.

I tried to create a BaseScreen stateful `with WidgetsBindingObserver` but don't work.

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.suspending:
        //offline or whatever
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        //active
        break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), here is an explanation on how to do it. [Example](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

Comment: Are you telling me to user a Provider to save my user state? But this would not send information to Firestore I guess. Would you be able to show a pratical example? Sorry I'm noob on flutter

Comment: With provider you can access state across al descendants widgets. Here is a example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrBiNHEqSYU

Comment: Why make something like this https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-firebase-login-using-provider-package-54ee4e5083c7 and not the Observer? Sorry I still don't understand why a provider is better to communicate with Firebase since I already use a StateModel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Flutter, but you can try using a [Cloud Firestore Presence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence), you could use it to display a list of friends that are online and free to chat.

Keep in mind that Cloud Firestore doesn't natively support presence, but you can leverage other Firebase products to build a presence system.

In that case, they used Cloud Functions with Realtime Database.

Hope this is helpful! :D

Comment: My only problem is send to firestore/fcm the user presence. People say that it's possible with Provider but I have no idea where to start

Answer (score 0):

You need to add observer on the `WidgetsBinding.instance` to listen for AppLifeCycleState:

```
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
 }
```